# What does it mean that a function can be defined as convex combinations of $q$ vertices $\theta$?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-hulls

I am reading a paper now and it is stated that some function $\phi$ can be defined as convex combinations of  $q$ vertices $\theta$. According to this equation:

$$\phi(x, u, w) = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^q \mu_l(w) \phi(x, u, \theta_l) \\
\text{where:} \;\;\>  \mu_l(w)\geq 0 \\
 \text{and:} \;\;\> \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^q \mu_l(w) =1.$$

I look forward to just simply understand this in a very basic way, this is just side note in the paper.

Comment: Do you not understand what is a convex combination? Or is the formation of the function $\phi$ bothering you? Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: No, I don't actually. Thank you :)

Comment: The conditions on the $\mu_l$ that you gave above are exactly the definition of a convex combination. It is a special type of linear combination.    https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3276220

Comment: So, does this mean we are expressing it as a linear combination of the boundaries?

Comment: @BassemSALEH If you look at the 2D plane where it's easier to visualize, the [convex combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of two points represent the segment between the two points, the convex combinations of three points represent the interior of the triangle including the sides, and in general the convex combinations of $n$ points represent the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the $n$ points. The latter generalizes to arbitrary spaces.

Comment: That clears it, thank you very much. The second part of the statement says vertices, does that mean the boundaries of the set?

Comment: @BassemSALEH No, a vertex is a point, which may or may not be on the boundary. Consider for example the four points (vertices) $A,B,C,O$ where $ABC$ form a non-degenerate triangle, and $O$ is a point strictly inside the triangle. Then the boundary (of the convex hull) is the union of the segments $AB \cup BC \cup CA$, and vertices $A,B,C$ are on the boundary, but vertex $O$ is not on the boundary.

Comment: I understand it now, Thank you very much for your help guys. @dxiv